# Circular Reference on preFlush

Tags: php, symfony, circular-reference

I'm having some trouble with my dependency injection. I'm trying to save a record to the DB in my preFlush listener. I'm saving this record to the DB via my own service ( A custom logging service ). I've tried this a few ways but none are working, I've tried every google / stackover flow result I've found but no luck yet I'm afraid.

Here's the setup for my logger class, all private variables have been ommitted but are set ( I use the request stack and the translator else where in the class, wasn't sure if I should ommit for this question ):

Config:

```
core.logger:
    class: xxx\CoreBundle\Logger
    arguments: [@request_stack, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @translator]
```

Class:

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManager $em, TranslatorInterface $t)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->em = $em
        $this->t = $t;
    }
public function addLogEntityChange($uow, $entity) {
        $changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
        foreach($changeset as $key => $value) {
            $logEntity = new Log();
            //setStuff..
            $this->em->persist($logEntity);
        }
        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

And here's my Interface code

Config:

```
xxxcore.loggerlistener:
  class: xxx\CoreBundle\Listener\LoggerListener
  calls:
    - [ setLogger, [@core.logger] ]
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush }
```

Interface:

```
    public function setLogger($logger)
    {
        $this->l = $logger;
    }
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $uow->computeChangeSets();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if($entity instanceof LoggerInterface) {
                $this->l->addLogEntityChange($uow, $entity);
            }

        }
    }
```

This leads to the

```
Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.xxx_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.xxx_connection".
```

I've tried setting the entity manager in the logger class manually, so removing the dependancy injection and using a setEntityManager function but this just timesout the page. I've tried inserting the service_container but this didnt really help either.

When calling the functions manually after I persist an entity it all works, but I would like to automate this via the interface with the preFlush listener.

Any help / insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doctrine events can be tricky.  I think that fact that your logger calls flush is kicking off the onFlush again and causing a loop.  Consider making a second entity manager just for logging. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html.  Not sure if that will solve the problem or not.

Comment: My logging entity doesn't implement the LoggerInterface so it doesn't have the listener, and even if it did there is a check that it can't get past "if($entity instanceof LoggerInterface)". Atleast thats how it should be, right?

Comment: Nope.  Events are triggered by the event manager, not the individual entities.  LoggerListener::preFlush will get called every time EntityManager::flush is called.  Which means that every loggable entity will keep getting logged over and over.  Hence the need for a LoggerEntityManager.

Comment: Since you are calling this from the preFlush event, maybe you do not need to call flush in your logger service, a flush is already in process

Comment: Entity Log does not implement LoggerInterface, so it can't (or shouldn't ) pass the check in the preFlush method so there is no recursion.

Comment: Even when not making any calls the the logging service ( So just injecting it ) and doing nothing else in the preFlush method thows the Circular Reference error.

Comment: Hmmm.  Computing the change set in the preFlush is a bit unusual.  Consider trying the onFlush event, http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush without logging and see what happens.

Comment: As I said, even if I don't do anyting ( No computing )  in the preFlush method ( Totally empty ) it throws the  Circular Reference error.

Comment: Okay so it really has nothing to do with the doctrine listeners.  Your logger still won't work as posted but you first need to get past the di issue.  Please post your "doctrine.dbal.xxx_connection" definition or maybe your complete services.yml file.  Something else is cross linking two services.

Comment: Sadly I'm not at work at the moment so I can't access my files. I'll add those in tomorrow. I think the issue is that the Logger service is injecting an Entity Manager though I'm not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  This has come up before: [Symfony Circular Reference Exception for Doctrine onFlush Event Listener Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577801/symfony-circular-reference-exception-for-doctrine-onflush-event-listener-service)

Somewhere in the doctrine tagging process there must be a compiler pass that is injecting the listeners into the entity manager and causing a circular reference.

I checked the DoctrineBundle code and yep, the entity manager is dependent on it's listeners and of course if a listener is dependent on the entity manager then we get a circular reference.

I duplicated the problem with:

```
## services.yml
cerad_project_level_logger:
  class: Cerad\ProjectLevel\LevelLogger
  arguments:
    # - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

cerad_project_level_listener:
  class: Cerad\ProjectLevel\LevelListener
  arguments:
    - '@cerad_project_level_logger'
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush }
```

The work around is to pass the entity manager in the logger method instead of injecting it.

```
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if($entity instanceof LoggerInterface) {
            $this->l->addLogEntityChange($em, $uow, $entity);
        }
```

I'm fairly confident that your code will still not work as intended since preFlush is always called after em->flush and you will end up in a loop but at least this will get past the circular reference error.

All these problems will go away if you just make a logger entity manager.  Besides, do you really want to log to your production database?

Comment: I'm currently working on an internal tool so yeah, I want to log to the "production" database. I suppose I could give the logger its own entity manager since I'm not a fan of having to pass an EM to the logger service everytime I want to log something, because the service can also be called manually everywhere. Thanks for going above and beyond and reproducing the problem yourself. I'll play around tomorrow and see if I can get it working.

Comment: This indeed works, I tried this before but I indeed got stuck in that loop, I just didn't know I was in one. I've solved this by adding an extra check like this: 
`if($entity instanceof LoggerInterface && !isset($entity->logged)) {
    $entity->logged = TRUE;`
    ...
Thanks for all your help!