# Symfony circular reference with EventListener that depends on a service that requires EntityManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

For simplicity, I have a service 'TenantContext', that retrieves the current tenant from the database on each request and therefore requires the EntityManager.

Furthermore I want to associate all Entities that have a ManyToOne relationship with Tenant automatically just before a flush happens, so I implemented a TenantListener that will detect those entities and do the association (setTenant()). To do that, the TenantListener requires the TenantContext.

Here is my services.yml

```
services:
    tenant.service.tenant_context:
        class: TenantBundle\Context\TenantContext
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]

    tenant.event_listener.tenant_listener:
        class: TenantBundle\EventListener\TenantListener
        arguments: [ "@tenant.service.tenant_context" ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush }
```

This configuration gives me a circular reference error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]
  Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".
```

If I understand correctly, by tagging the EntityListener as a 'doctrine.event_listener' I am making the Doctrine EntityManager dependent on the TenantListener which depends on the TenantContext which again depends on the Doctrine EntityManager, etc.

I have looked into a similar post [Symfony Circular Reference Exception for Doctrine onFlush Event Listener Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577801/symfony-circular-reference-exception-for-doctrine-onflush-event-listener-service) but my situation is somehow different. The TenantContext is used in many different ways besides from the TenantListener and I can't always pass the Doctrine EntityManager to get the current tenant.

I can't see a solution to break this circle. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding a setEntityManager method to your TenantContext.  Sometimes using method injection gets around the circular dependency.  Otherwise, you just going to have to extract the TenantContext functionality into a third class which does not depend on the entity manager and then play games wiring them up.

Comment: Just tried the setter injection but I'm getting the same result. Will try to identify what could be extracted and fiddle a bit more. Thanks a lot for you quick answer.

Comment: Of course if this is really blocking you then you can always cheat and just inject the container into your listener and then pull the tenant from it.  A hack but at least it can get you going.

Comment: Thanks. Will have it in mind as a last resort, just when I realize I have to give up my pride ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You may do not want to inject the `EntityManager` but the Doctrine Registry to your `tenant.service.tenant_context` service:

```
services:
    tenant.service.tenant_context:
        class: TenantBundle\Context\TenantContext
        arguments: [ "@doctrine" ]
```

Example on how to access the `EntityManager` instance in your `TenantBundle\Context\TenantContext` class:

```
namespace TenantBundle\Context

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class TenantContext
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
    } 
}
```